# Flashplayer Gray exclamation error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

This was driving me mad for some time, today I manged to reproduce this problem, so one of the causes is division by 0.

e.g.

```
var end:Number = 1024/0,
    size:Number = 1000,
    a:Array = [];

for (var i:int=0;i<end;i++){
      a.push(size);
}
```

After dividing by 0 (I don't know how its possible, but anyway) value end becomes Infinity and sneaks into the loop, so flash player stops execution of the script with exclamation mark.

I discovered that when one of the components in flex, after state changes in layout, passed on its width of 0 as one of the parameters to construct the loop. How to avoid this behavior of flex component?

Comment: Don't divide by zero?

Comment: Primo: division just happens without developer effort, by changing size of the component as you may have noticed in description. Secundo: How flashplayer can allow divide by 0 and convert it to infinity?

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior in most, if not all, languages. I just tested AS3, Javascript, and PHP. AS3 and JS give you Infinity and PHP gives you `false` (PHP's go-to handler for if there is a low-level error). You should avoid dividing by 0 at all costs because it simply is not possible. Most languages do not want to prevent a user from dividing by 0, since Infinity is an actual value and the correct value of dividing by 0, which is why they allow it.

Your error is because you are using Infinity as your loop check, which will never be reached in your loop.

Instead, use a conditional to handle the possibility of the value being 0. So something like:

```
function calculateRatio(x:Number, y:Number):Number {
    if (y == 0) {
        return 1; // or whatever to indicate an error
    }
    return x / y;
}
```

or

```
function calculateRatio(x:Number, y:Number):Number {
    return x / (y == 0 ? 1 : y); // the value is still calculated, just makes sure y is not 0 at all times
}
```

Just make sure any time you perform division, you *never* divide by 0. In your case, your loop is running an infinite number of times. Flash is single-threaded and will actually freeze completely while any script execution is happening. Generally, this happens so quickly that the end-user doesn't notice it but in your case, it will freeze until the end of time. Fortunately, Flash will end script execution at 15s or 30s, depending on runtime version so it should error out at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Division by 0 is not a problem as such here, 0 is passed as a parameter, as a result of other operations at run-time, and I can not be sure, that 0 will not be passed as parameter.
What's boggling my mind is that division by 0 should be flagged in the first place, but it isn't. Then gets result of infinity, ok from mathematical point of view, but then I get infinite loop. I would normally expect that executing the script longer than e.g. 15 sec. throw an error and the script stops, but instead what I have is exclamation sign without any information for the developer, and that sucks..